# CodeIgniter how to unlike image

Tags: codeigniter

I want to delete image from database as well as from folder

Controller

```
function delete_projects(){
    $this->load->model('m_insert_data');
    $this->m_insert_data->delete_projects();
    redirect('../c_home/projects', 'refresh');
}
```

model

```
function delete_projects(){
    $this->db->where('p_id',$this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->db->delete('projects');
}
```

Comment: Ok.  So, what's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `delete` syntax correct, so presumably you are removing it from the DB.

It looks like all you need to do is remove it from the file system. To do this, you would use [`unlink`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php).

I might structure it a tad differently, however:

```
function delete_projects(){
    $this->load->model('m_insert_data');
    // You will want this ID more than once.
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $this->m_insert_data->remove_file($id);
    $this->m_insert_data->delete_projects($id);
    redirect('../c_home/projects', 'refresh');
}
```

model

```
function remove_file($id){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('projects', array('p_id' => $id))->result();
    if($query) {
       // assumes that there is a column "path" in the projects table
       // which represents the path to the file
       unlink($query->path);
    }
}

function delete_projects($id){
    // generally a good idea to have functions like this know as little 
    // about the outside world as possible. So pass $id as a param
    $this->db->where('p_id',$id);
    $this->db->delete('projects');
}
```

Comment: `if($query)` will be always true even if the record is not found.it should be `if($query->resullt())`

Comment: even `$query->result()->path` will produce error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: thank you sir for replying me  but it is showing me that error 

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: models/m_insert_data.php

Line Number: 77

Comment: sir this is my model code 
 
     
  function remove_file($id){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('projects', array('p_id' => $id))->result();
 
    if($query) {
       
       unlink('http://localhost/lahor/'.$query->file);
    }
}

Comment: Hi Just replace this answer's following line `$query = $this->db->get_where('projects', array('p_id' => $id))->result();` with `$query = $this->db->get_where('projects', array('p_id' => $id))->row();` it will solve the error.

Comment: thanku sir for ur reply now sir it give me that error (Severity: Warning

Message: unlink(localhost/lahor/uploads/f8912cbbdc9d0bc5809614eee513f8ee.PNG) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory

Filename: models/m_insert_data.php

Line Number: 78)    but when i copy the link(localhost/lahor/uploads/f8912cbbdc9d0bc5809614eee513f8ee.PNG) in the browser then it show me the image in the same location but in the codes it show me that error

Comment: but when i change location like that then it works 

     function remove_file($id){ 
   
   $query = $this->db->get_where('projects', array('p_id' => $id))->row();

 unlink('C:/xampp/htdocs/lahor/uploads/'.$query->file); 
  
}